# How to make an object for JSONObject who contain a JSONArray using Retrofit

Tags: android

I am using Retrofit for my app. For a GET call ( name : **/sequences/** ) I have to make an object for this `JSONObject` :

```
{
  "listeIds": [
    "12",
    "15",
    "23",
    "19",
    "94",
    "78",
    "87",
    "32"
  ]
}
```

So, my `JSONObject` contain one `JSONArray` named **"listeIds"**.

I don't know how I can make an object called **Sequences** where I can put the **listeIds**.

Do I have to make an object in my object like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815008/using-retrofit-to-access-json-arrays) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use `gson` as converter, this should work for you.

```
public class Sequences {
    List<String> listeIds;
}
```